# change text color in a textbox dynamically in C#

Tags: c#

is there any alternative that can be used to change the text color in a textbox dynamically apart from `ColorTranslator.FromHtml(#F9DA00)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an attribute or style...

```
myTextbox.Attributes.Add("style", "color:#000000");
```

or

```
myTextbox.Styles.Add("color", "#000000");
```